# How come Visual Studio doesn't recognize RuntimeBinderException?

Tags: c#, exception, compiler-errors

```
using System.Dynamic;

...

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ...
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic CBT = new CustomBindingTest();
            CBT.DynamicMethodExample();
        }
    }

    public class CustomBindingTest : DynamicObject
    {
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(binder.Name);
            try { return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result); }
            catch (RuntimeBinderException e) { result = null;  return false; }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error: `The type or namespace name 'RuntimeBinderException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Is this a limitation of VS Express (2012), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the following namespace and assembly reference included:

Namespace:  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder

A "using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder" statement should fix that.

Assembly:  Microsoft.CSharp (in Microsoft.CSharp.dll)

1. Right click on the References folder on your project.
2. Select Add Reference.
3. Select the .NET tab (or select the Browse button if it is not a .NET Framework assembly).
4. Double-click the assembly containing the namespace in the error message.
5. Press the OK button.

Comment: Doh. Looked in quite a few places and never saw any mention of `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder`. Would've figured this would be in `System.Dynamic`. Strange. Thanks man!